# file.createNewFile() show the exception?

Tags: android, file, printwriter

In my project,I need gather the crash messages.The following is my demo,the code goes to `file.createNewFile()` it will throw the exception,said that not such file or directory,please help me. I don't know why this is.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Myself throw a exception……");
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static MyApplication sMyApplication;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // 在这里为应用设置异常处理，然后程序才能获取未处理的异常
        CrashHandler crashHandler = CrashHandler.getInstance();
        crashHandler.init(this);
    }
    public static MyApplication getInstance(){
        return sMyApplication;
    }
}

    public class CrashHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private static final String TAG = "CrashHandler";
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    private static final String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/CrashTest/log/";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "crash";
    private static final String FILE_NAME_SUFFIX = ".trace";

    private static CrashHandler sCrashHandler = new CrashHandler();
    private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultCrashHandler;
    private Context mContext;


    private CrashHandler(){}

    // 单例模式
    public static CrashHandler getInstance(){
        return sCrashHandler;
    }

    public void init(Context context){
        mDefaultCrashHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    /**
     * 这是最关键的函数，当程序中有未捕获的异常，系统将会自动调用此方法
     * @param thread  为出现未捕获异常的线程
     * @param exception 未捕获的异常，有了此异常，我们就能得到异常信息
     */
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        try {
            //save exception message to sdcard
            saveExceptionToSDCard(exception);
            //upload exception message to web server
            uploadExceptionToServer(exception);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // 如果系统提供了默认的异常处理器，就交给系统自己处理，否则就自己结束掉自己
        if (mDefaultCrashHandler!=null){
            mDefaultCrashHandler.uncaughtException(thread,exception);
        }else {
            Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        }
    }


    // 将异常信息保存到SDCard
    private void saveExceptionToSDCard(Throwable ex) throws IOException {
        // 如果SD卡不存在或无法使用，则无法写入异常信息，给与提示
        if(!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            if (DEBUG){
                Log.w(TAG,"sdcard unmounted , skip save exception"); //sd卡未安装好，跳出存储异常
            }
            return;
        }
        // 文件存储路径
        File dir = new File(PATH);
        if (!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        // 获取当前时间
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(current));
        // 创建存储异常信息的文件
        File file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+FILE_NAME+time+FILE_NAME_SUFFIX);
        if (!file.exists()){
            try {
                file.createNewFile();     //I debug when code goes to here will throw exception
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));
            pw.print(time);
            savePhoneInfo(pw);
            pw.println();
            ex.printStackTrace(pw);   //输出异常信息
            pw.close();
        }catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"save crash info failed");
        }

    }

    // 保存手机的信息
    private void savePhoneInfo(PrintWriter pw) throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);

        // APP的版本信息
        pw.print("APP Version:");
        pw.print(pi.versionName);
        pw.print('_');
        pw.print(pi.versionCode);

        // Android 手机版本号
        pw.print("OS Version:");
        pw.print(Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
        pw.print('_');
        pw.print(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);

        // 手机制造商
        pw.print("Vendor:");
        pw.print(Build.MANUFACTURER);

        // 手机型号
        pw.print("Model:");
        pw.print(Build.MODEL);

        // CPU架构
        pw.print("CUP ABI:");
        pw.print(Build.CPU_ABI);
    }

    // 将异常信息上传到服务器
    private void uploadExceptionToServer(Throwable ex){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `saveExceptionToSDCard()` change `dir.mkdir()` to `dir.mkdirs()`